# Different results in same query postgresql/jpa

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I faced strange thing
i have a postgres database ,table respondent with column type Date
then i made a query :

```
select count(*) from respondent p where (select extract( year from age(p.birth_date)))  between  76 and 90 and p.space_id=1 and deleted_at is null;
```

and get result 149824

i do same in java code

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RespondentFilterService {

  private final EntityManager em;
  private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

  public long getCountRespondent () {
    .....
    var query = em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from respondent p where  (select extract( year from age(p.birth_date))) between :min and :max and p.space_id = :spaceId and p.deleted_at is null");

      query.setParameter("min",76);
      query.setParameter("max",90);
    query.setParameter("spaceId", 1);
return ((BigInteger)(query.getSingleResult())).longValue()
   
}
```

in debuger i see the same query

```
select count(*) from respondent p where  (select extract( year from age(p.birth_date))) between :min and :max and p.space_id = :spaceId and p.deleted_at is null
```

and same parameters ib parameterBindingMap

```
spaceId {Long@erqefd12} 1
min {Integer@weqc23} 76
min {Integer@w1ssdfs} 90
```

and this method return 149855

i dont know whats going wrong and why same query return different results

Comment: the parameters binding map is binding min twice? `spaceId {Long@erqefd12} 1
min {Integer@weqc23} 76
min {Integer@w1ssdfs} 90`

Comment: no,the binding map contains parameters like these

Comment: spaceId {Long@erqefd12} 1
min {Integer@weqc23} 76
min {Integer@w1ssdfs} 90

Comment: Can you add your table declaration / column types?

Comment: I found what is going wrong - its all about the ppl who have birthday today like '1930-06-21' and select from console return this age =91 ,but jpa native query return 90 its all about how to decide that someone have +1 year to age ,jpa give +1 year at first second of next day from birthday .